# How to use the power function in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

I tried calling power(x, 100), but it didn't work.

```sql
create table test(a float, tags(b));
select power(a, 100) from test;
```

The result is as follows:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: simplify_expressions\ncaused by\nInternal error: Optimizer rule 'simplify_expressions' failed due to unexpected error: Internal error: The expr has more than one schema, could not determine data type. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker. This was likely caused by a bug in DataFusion's code and we would welcome that you file an bug report in our issue tracker"}
```

Is there any way to be able to call the power function?